# Magento Error after I deleted Cache and session files

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, fatal-error

I am giving up finding a solution to my problem and hence I came here to get help from you experts.

I had my website smoothly running on Magento 2.0.0 until four days ago when I just wanted to speed up the site and in the process, I deleted some files like Cache, sessions, and files from a couple of other folders I exactly don't remember.
And the biggest foolish work I did was I did not take a backup as I thought the server will have a backup by default which they did not have to add to my frustration.

The problem now is - I am getting all sorts of error on the site.

1) Themes and JS have stopped working from frontend and backend. 
2) Errors on all the inner pages in the frontend which I do not recognize.

I don't know how to solve it.
Please help. 
Error is listed below which comes on every page in frontend:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/herbalre/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Gallery.php on line 112

Comment: Sorry, Mayank. I gave and migrated to Woocommerce on that site.

Answer (score 6):

Hope this will help you

You can try this in your CLI:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy